# Delete n last relationship neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph that contains a relationship between users, showing what user has liked another's profile, and when:

`(liker:User)-[:LIKED]->(target:User)`

But I don't want to store every like since the beggining of time. I only want the last 200 users that a user has liked. So before adding a new relationship I must delete the 201th relationship, but I don't know how to delete it.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a bit more information in your schema as you need to know the order the 'liker's are attached to the 'target's in order to delete the 201st. Note: You cannot rely on the sort order of `id(rel)` being in the order that targets were liked as ids are reused.

Assume you add a `dateTime`, `likedOn` property to the `:LIKED` relationship, the you could perform somethin like:

```
MATCH (liker:User)-[rel:LIKED]-(target:User) 
WITH rel 
ORDER BY rel.likeOn DESC 
SKIP 200 
DELETE rel
```

You need to sort the relationship in descending order so that you keep the latest targets at the top of the intermediate result set in order skip them and delete the targets that have been liked the longest.

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH (:User {username: "Bobby"})-[r:LIKED]->(:User)
WITH r ORDER BY r.date DESC SKIP 200
DELETE r
```